# Why does calculating $\exp z$ using $\ln z$ via newton-raphson method fail to converge?

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods, exponential-function, recursive-algorithms, newton-raphson

I am trying to calculate $\exp z$ using $\ln z$ via Newton-Raphson method $$x_{n+1} = x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f^{'}(x_n)}$$and got the formula $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\ln x_n-z}{\frac{1}{x_n}}$$ where $z = a + bi$ is the value i'm trying to iterate to. However this formula only converges when $-3< b < 3$. But, if $z$ is instead any real number the formula converges accurately. Why does the formula not converge to any complex $z$, and how can I fix it so that it does?

Comment: It's almost certainly a problem with the branching of the complex log.

Comment: yes it means that b has to be less that 3 and greater than -3 to converge towards $e^z$

Comment: Randall can you go more into detail about the branching of the complex log?

Comment: Not really, because it's been 20 years since I thought about this stuff intimately.  You need someone with a better answer, who will certainly be along shortly.   But, the complex exponential is not one-to-one, so what do you mean by "$\ln z$"?

Comment: The complex logarithm is $ln(z)$ and I know that $ln(z)$ is multivalued, along with $e^z$ like the trigonometric functions however, the formula should still be able to evaluate over all complex numbers right?

Comment: If you simplify that fraction by moving $x_n$ up to the top it might make it easier to think about. You end up with $x_n$ multiplied by an expression that looks as though it has every chance of being big enough to diverge to infinity if the wrong range of complex $x_n$ gets into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex, principal logarithm $\text{Log}(z)$ is defined by
$$
\text{Log}(z) = \ln|z| + i \ \text{Arg}(z),
$$
where $\text{Arg}$ stands for the principal argument of $z$ - that is $\text{Arg}(z)$ represents the angle that $z$ makes against the positive real axis when viewed in polar form. By the *principal* argument, we mean that
$$-\pi < \text{Arg}(z) \leq \pi.$$
As a result, $\text{Log}(w) = z$ has no solution if $|\text{Im}(z)|>\pi$ so you cannot to expect to use that formulation to compute $e^z$.

To fix this, you can define your own branch of the logarithm with the appropriate value of it's imaginary part. For example, since 
12 is between $3\pi$ and $5\pi$, you can define your logarithm by
$$
\text{LOG}(z) = \ln|z| + i \ (\text{Arg}(z) + 4\pi).
$$
[Here's a simple implementation in Sage.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=gnykif).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, it's like how arccosine needs to have a domain restriction, because otherwise it wouldn't be a function.

Comment: That's exactly right. The complex exponential is periodic with period $2\pi i$ so you can define a branch of the logarithm whose range lies in a strip of height $2\pi$.

Comment: Just wondering why did you choose $4\pi$ wouldn't $5\pi$ also work?

Comment: We know that $-\pi<Arg(z)\leq \pi$ so I added on two periods of $2\pi i$ each to get $3\pi < Arg(z)\leq 5\pi$ which works since 12 is between these numbers. More generally, you want to add on some integer multiple of the period $2\pi i$ so i wouldn't expect $+5\pi$ to work.